# Access same resource ID in two files

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

How can I access same resource ID from two different files.
Example in Java:

```
public final class Strings_v1 {
    String one = "AAAA";
    String two = "BBBB";
    String three = "CCCC";
}

public final class Strings_v2 {
    String one = "DDDD";
    String two = "EEEE";
    String three = "FFFF";
}
```

Now I can access `Strings_v1.one` and `Strings_v2.one`

Is it possible to do the same in XML ?

Comment: It is possible only if you have created two different projects - one should be a library and second should use this library. These progect should also have different package names in their manifests.

Comment: in your case, the attribute's name must be unique! you can do that if you define another folder like "value-fr" for internationalization

Comment: Is there a way to define "value-mystrings1" and "value-mystrings2" and accessing them.

Comment: I edited my question code.

Answer (score 1):

The closest way to do this is to use string arrays. For example, you could define a resources file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="strings_v1">
        <item>AAAA</item>
        <item>BBBB</item>
        <item>CCCC</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array
            name="strings_v2">
        <item>AAAA</item>
        <item>BBBB</item>
        <item>CCCC</item>
        </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then, in your Java code, you would have to fetch the whole array before using it:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] strings_v1 = res.getStringArray(R.array.strings_v1);
String[] strings_v2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.strings_v2);
//Assuming an array of textViews
ActivityManager activityMgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    (activityMgr.isUserAMonkey())? textView[i].setText(strings_v1[i]) : textView[i].setText(strings_v2[i]);
```

Can you explain why you would want to do this, as there might be a different way to approach the problem?

Comment: For example a user selected some configuration from: config_1, config_2, config_3. Now I want to use the same names (one, two, three) in my code and just choose different config_ .

Comment: You answer didn't use names to get Strings: one, two, three. You are using index number